# Обработка определённых строк в текстовых файлах

Tags: linux, bash

1. В одном из текстовых файлов во всех чётных строках перенести первое слово строки в конец строки. Строки, содержащие только одно слово, не изменяются.
2. В одном из текстовых файлов удалить вторую строку, заканчивающуюся на знак `-` (минус).

Используйте команды head, tail, sed, pr и др., кроме awk. Не используйте более одного вспомогательного файла. В крайнем случае, можно использовать конструкции for, while и др. с обоснованием оправданности.

Comment: @Mike, хотел пояснить на этом примере один из аспектов работы sed. [По поводу отношения](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4838/183314): я пытался это выяснить, но так до конца и не разобрался с этим.

Comment: Такое условие задачи мне попалось (про sed там упоминается лишь мелком, а метки относятся к вопросу), и я не старался мудрить ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: [уже находится](https://www.google.ru/search?q=в+чётных+строках+перенести+первое+слово+в+конец+строки)

Comment: Конечно он найдет дословно эту строку. но кто будет искать по такой фразе ? разве что только тот, кто получил точно такое же задание. Я вот спросил "sed модификация четных строк" я нашел ответ. только не ваш. И вообще я имел ввиду поиск прямо тут на сайте. например мне интересны всякие фокусы на sed, я тут в поиске введу `[sed]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sed -i 'n;s/\(\w\+\)\W*\(.\+\)/\2 \1/' file.txt`

   Данный скрипт для sed состоит из двух команд (ну и кучи слешей, кончено же) и
   выполняется так:

   - Утилита начинает работать с первой строчки (которая получается нечётной).
   - К ней применяется первая команда. `n` — вывести текущую строку и перейти к
     следующей.
   - Затем обрабатывается вторая (чётная) строка. `s/.../\2 \1/` — замена по
     регулярному выражению.
   - В регулярке присутствуют две группы захвата (в скобках, предварёнными
     обратными косыми чертами). `\w\+` соответствует первому слову в строке,
     `.\+` подходит под всю оставшуюся часть строки. Между этим
     группами наличествует `\W*` — означает набор разделителей между словами.
   - В подстановочной строке упомянуты номера групп в обратном порядке, чтобы
     обменять местами слова.
   - Затем sed переходит с следующей строке (которая оказывается нечётной) и
     выполняет скрипт заново.
2. `sed -i '2{/-$/d}' file.txt`

   В отличие от предыдущего этот скрипт начинается с адреса — номера строки — к
   которому применяется команда. Команда в свою очередь представляет собой новый
   блок команд — так сказать, подскрипт — который также начинается с адреса —
   регулярного выражения. На этот раз регулярка попроще и проверяет, что в конце
   строки есть минус. Затем следует команда «удалить» — просто `d`

Обо всех командах и синтаксисе можно узнать в руководстве [sed(1)](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sed&category=1).